# Preserve directory on build docker/gcloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcloud

**Blank Stare:**
How can I prevent the directory structure created by an app from being deleted (overwritten) when a build is triggered by a change in an attached repo?

**Scenario:**
Web app running on google cloud using Docker/Kubernetes. Build is triggered by push to repo at Bitbucket.

**Problem:**
After the build the app is brand spanking new, dirs/files that had been created by the app are wiped away.

**Unicorn Objective:**
Preserve the dirs/files that the app has created, carrying them over to the new build OR skip the full build and do something similar to a git pull when the trigger fires.

Current build steps as reported by Google:

```
gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
pull [details...]

gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
build -t [details...]

gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
set image [details...]
```

Comment: Yes, that’s how Docker/Kubernetes work.  If you need state to be preserved you need to set up some sort of storage.  Do you have any of the actual Kubernetes YAML artifacts you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data persistence (your application generated data) should always be handled outside of the build process.

You have a couple of options where you could "mount" a file system locally to the container:

1. PersistentVolume/PersistentVolumeClaim (you can provision a persistent volume within your cluster and mount it within your pod(s), see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes)
2. NFS (you can deploy an NFS server within your cluster and use a PVC to mount the volume to your pod(s), for a live example+video see: https://matthewdavis.io/highly-available-wordpress-on-kubernetes)
3. Mount a google cloud storage bucket using GCS Fuse as a local file system (see: https://github.com/mateothegreat/k8-byexamples-gcsfuse)

Hope this helps!
If you still need a hand please reach out and supply some more details about your applications data structure, types and sizes.